# Name Error: Global name 'r' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

Ive been working on this sample code for a while and cant seem to wrap my head around this seemingly simple error.

The code is as follows:

```
class area :

    r=5
    l=2
    b=3

    def __init__(self,r,l,b):
        print "parent constructor"
        self.r=r
        self.l=l
        self.b=b

    def __del__(self):
        print "parent deconstructor"

    def circle(self):

        circle_area= 3.14 * r * r
        print "area of circle is :",circle_area 

    def rectangle(self):
        rect_area=l*b
        print "area of rectangle :",rect_area

obj=area(4,5,4)
obj2=area(2,5,4)

obj.circle()
```

The error message says :

```
File "yaa.py", line 18, in circle
    circle_area= 3.14 * r * r
NameError: global name 'r' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the self for refering class attributes:

```
def circle(self):
    circle_area= 3.14 * self.r * self.r
    print "area of circle is :",circle_area
```

In case you want to use the `r` within the class, not the instance you have to use the name of the class then:

```
def circle(self):
    circle_area= 3.14 * area.r * area.r
    print "area of circle is :",circle_area
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to change your method `circle(self)` from

```
circle_area= 3.14 * r * r
```

to

```
circle_area= 3.14 * self.r * self.r
```

because `r` is an attribute of the class, not a global variable.

---

The same goes for your method `rectangle(self)`:

```
rect_area = self.l * self.b
```